# .NET API is not inserting into SQL Server, but there are no errors

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I added Web API to in order to receive Json and insert the contents into SQL Server. On the mobile Cordova app, and in a Rest Api test, I get Http status of 200. There is however no record inserted.

Here is the class and `DBContext`:

```
public class MobileController : ApiController
{
    private PTSContext db = new PTSContext();

   //all the code....
}
```

I created this class to handle json body from the Http request.

```
public class DailyCrewActivityJson
{
    [JsonProperty("api_id")]
    public string api_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("api_daily_crew_id")]
    public string api_daily_crew_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("api_contract_id")]
    public string api_contract_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("api_contract_task_id")]
    public string api_contract_task_id { get; set; }

}
```

I have this class to handle the insert.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/mobile/insertdailycrewactivity")]
public IHttpActionResult InsertDailyCrewActivity([FromBody] DailyCrewActivityJson crewActivityJson)
{
    DailyCrewActivity d = new DailyCrewActivity();
    d.id = crewActivityJson.api_id;
    d.daily_crew_id = crewActivityJson.api_daily_crew_id;
    d.contract_id = crewActivityJson.api_contract_id;
    d.contract_task_id = crewActivityJson.api_contract_task_id;

    db.DailyCrewActivities.Add(d);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

Does this pattern look ok? I try to manually execute a POST from advanced REST client and I still don't get an insert or an error.

This is what my url and my json body looks like:

```
https://<my url.com>/api/mobile/insertdailycrewactivity
```

JSON:

```
{
  "api_id": "74849939162039260-1569958529936",
  "api_daily_crew_id": "21273665486597612-1569862557128",
  "api_contract_id": "eef03be7-82b9-4066-93d9-cb64d346481c",
  "api_contract_task_id": "00407436-2450-4f40-9323-29860232e8f7",
}
```

***EDIT 10/5/2019***
I moved the site locally and restored the SQL Database to my local SQL Express. When I run the site and call

```
http://localhost/api/mobile/insertdailycrewactivity
```

I can step through that web api method. My error(s) are occuring in the db.SaveChanges method.

The error is from System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal and states "{Invalid column name 'DailyCrew_id'}"
I don't have a column with that name. I do have a column named 'daily_crew_id' and I have a table called 'DailyCrew' with an 'id' field.
Would 'DailyCrew_id' be a name in the internal list? 
I don't know where to look or how to fix this.

Comment: The pattern that you are using looks correct. You new up an EF class, set properties, add it to the sub class (DailyCrewActivities) of your Entity class, and `.SaveChanges()`. That's what you've done here... Is that the complete method? Do you have any validation in there that you're not showing? How about the `db.` object? Where and how is that declared?

Comment: I updated the question to show the class and dbcontext declaration. "db" is the ef dbcontext

Comment: If I am testing this on a remote server, how can I get feedback on what it is doing? Do I place console messages in the code?

Comment: If you have no access to the remote environment, you can always put diagnostics into your HTTP response.  Especially make sure your database connection is pointing where you expect it to.

Comment: Why are you troubleshooting on remote? Is it because it works locally but not remotely? If so, probably a configuration difference between the environments; otherwise, you should be trying to troubleshoot locally where you can step through your code. Right now, you are returning 200OK regardless of what's happening on the server, so you should likely update that, and perhaps return the full exception (if it exists) in your response.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I am going to add a try/catch (should have done that in the first place). I will update the response too.

Comment: @Ryan If I may make a suggestion, get into the habit of setting up logging in your projects, especially if those projects run in a remote environment.  Either log to a file or to a database.  log4net, Serilog, and NLog are both excellent libraries for this, but there are others.  When something happens badly in the remote environment, this will give you better visibility into *why*.

Comment: Also, pattern wise, DBContext implements IDisposable. With how you're declaring it at the top of your Controller like that, you need to make sure that Dispose() is called once you're done with it somewhere. Your other options can be that you create your db context in each controller method with a `using` statement or you can implement something like `Unity Dependency Injection` which manages the lifetime of the object and disposes of it for you. Not calling dispose on an object can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you all. I added some additional info from testing.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that EF did not like the naming conventions I was using for tables and fields and so it was not able to establish relationships between keys. I had annotated properties as Key and Foreign Key but after I changed naming of properties to something that EF liked, then it all worked.

Answer (score -3):

What happen inside

```
 db.DailyCrewActivities.Add(d);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I believe  you have implement your db insert logic in

> SaveChanges()

The reason you are getting always Http status as 200 is in in your method you always    returns

> return Ok();

please add the SaveChanges() method implementation

Comment: `.SaveChanges()` is a built-in method of entity Framework. It is what makes the persistence call to the database